# Two Winforms. One in Fullscreen, the other one in Normal Size. How can I prevent clicking on the fullscreen form to hide the other form?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I've got two Winforms. One is in fullscreen and the other one is in the normal size. The second comes over the first. It is something like this:

[image: click here]

The problem is, when I click the form in fullscreen, the form that looks like a Message Box will hide. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You should open the second form as a Modal Form or as a Modal Dialog.

Comment: Call ``ShowDialog`` instead of ``Show`` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I didn't know what a modal form is, so I probably wouldn't get to that question.
The thing with ShowDialog did it :) Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help the fastest. :)

Comment: This doesn't require the ShowDialog() hammer, setting the Owner is enough to ensure it stays on top and gets minimized along with the main window.

Answer (score 0):

When showing the child window or form you have to use ShowDialog()

```
Form childForm = new Form();
childForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

Assuming that `childForm` is the small window and `this` is the parent form.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter B mentioned in his comment, you'll want to make the new non-fullscreen window a Modal Dialog. This will make the smaller window behave as a dialog box of the bigger one (if the smaller is created from the bigger one).
You can use `ShowDialog` instead of `Show`as Rand Random suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Open your normal form like below :

```
Form f = new Form();
f.ShowDialog(this);
```